# Strapi deployment with Oracle DB on K8s fails with OCIEnvCreate error. Verified DB and env variables. How to troubleshoot and resolve?

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, strapi

Strapi deployment with Oracle 19c on Kubernetes encounters persistent error. Verified DB connectivity, environment variables, and tried without volume. Need guidance to troubleshoot and resolve the issue.as i am not much familiar with k8s